# CAGradientLayer Opacity property

Tags: iphone, calayer, quartz-graphics

I have a CAGradientLayer that I want to hide sometimes.  The .hidden is a read-only property.  The CAGRadientLayer is added as a sublayer to my view.  I put in NSLog statements to see if my conditions are being hit and they are the way I want.  However, sometimes the .opacity = 0.0 does hide the layer, sometimes it doesn't.  Has anyone else had consistency problems with this?  Is there a  better way to hide the layer?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you say that the `hidden` property is readonly? It's writable:

```
/* When true the layer and its sublayers are not displayed. Defaults to
 * false. Animatable. */

@property(getter=isHidden) BOOL hidden;
```

Comment: Right.  I found that later that's why I tried closing the question.  When I would use XCode, and I would type "layer." and then hit the escape key for the codesense to pop up, the hidden property says read-only for some reason.  That's why I thought it was read-only until I dug further.  Thanks.